# OpenCV: How to pass cv::Ptr as argument?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to pass a `cv::Ptr` as argument to a function and I am not sure how to do it. Shall I pass it by reference, or by value? I know that `std::auto_ptr` is pretty ugly if I pass it as value and not as reference.

So:

```
void foo(cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector) { /*...*/ }
```

or

```
void foo(cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>& detector) { /*...*/ }
```

?

And, if I use `const`, what is the difference:

```
void foo(const cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector) { /*...*/ }
void foo(const cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>& detector) { /*...*/ }
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::Ptr` is an object.
See other related questions and answers like this: [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

`cv::Ptr` is a pointer-like type, which means it provides reference semantics. If you have a `cv::Ptr` that is `const`, it only gives you `const` access to the object it is pointing at.  This is actually a strange quirk, because normal pointers and the standard smart pointers do not work in this way. Your choice of function depends on whether you need to be able to modify the `cv::FeatureDetector`.

If you need to modify it, your two choices are:

```
void foo(cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector) { /*...*/ }
void foo(cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>& detector) { /*...*/ }
```

The overhead of copying the `cv::Ptr` is likely to be minimal (or at least have no effect on your program). I typically see any non-`const` reference parameter as being an "output parameter", which suggests that the `cv::Ptr` itself is going to modified. But due to the quirkiness of `cv::Ptr`, what this really means is that it is allowing `cv::FeatureDetector` to be modified. To avoid this confusion, I would much prefer the value parameter.

I assume you're using C++03 because you mentioned `std::auto_ptr`, but if you ever upgrade to C++11 and if OpenCV adds a move constructor to `cv::Ptr`, you'll also have the benefits of move semantics.

If you want to express that the `cv::FeatureDetector` will not be modified, you can make the parameters `const`. This ensures that you do not modify the `cv::FeatureDetector` inside your function. Your choices are:

```
void foo(const cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector) { /*...*/ }
void foo(const cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>& detector) { /*...*/ }
```

This first one is really no different from the non-`const` value parameter from the outside.